# OnlineDisassembler is down - any alternative?

Tags: disassemblers

Since weeks my beloved and favorite site www.onlinedisassembler.com is down and shows server error 500.
Does anybody know any alternative for trying different microcontroller architetures on an unknown binary file?

Comment: Not as easy to use IMHO, but this site provides a web interface to the keystone/capstone assembler and disassembler libraries: http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one (for x86 and AMD64): https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use it (Beta Version in the Cloud)! https://beta.onlinedisassembler.com/oda/#/odaweb/ntFgQpjT

https://twitter.com/m2ksec/status/954802442524[image]348416